Error when using pd.read_hdf with Dask: "cannot properly create the storer for: [_TABLE_MAP] [group->/a (Group)]
I'm encountering an issue while trying to read an HDF5 file using Dask and Pandas in a Python script. The error I see is related to creating a storer for an HDF5 group.
Code
from pickletools import read_uint1
from random import sample
from pyJoules.energy_meter import measure_energy
from pyJoules.handler.csv_handler import CSVHandler

csv_handler = CSVHandler('dask_adult.csv')
import time
# import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as pd

def sleep():
    time.sleep(10)

# I/O functions - READ
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def load_csv(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def load_hdf(path, key):
    return pd.read_hdf(path, key=key)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def load_json(path):
    return pd.read_json(path, orient=str)

# I/O functions - WRITE
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def save_csv(df, path):
    return df.to_csv(path)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def save_hdf(df, path, key):
    return df.to_hdf(path, key=key)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def save_json(df, path):
    return df.to_json(path)

###------------------------------------------###

# Handling missing data 
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def isna(df, cname):
    return df[cname].isna()

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def dropna(df):
    return df.dropna()

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def fillna(df, val):
    return df.fillna(val)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def replace(df, cname, src, dest):
    return df[cname].replace(src, dest)

###------------------------------------------###

# Table operations
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def drop(df, cnameArray):
    return df.drop(columns=cnameArray)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def groupby(df, cname):
    return df.groupby(cname)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def merge(df1, df2, on=None):
    if(on):
        return pd.merge(df1, df2, on=on)
    else:
        return pd.merge(df1, df2)

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def sort(df, cname):
    return df.sort_values(by=[cname])

# def transpose(df):
#     return df.transpose()

@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def concat_dataframes(df1, df2):
    return pd.concat([df1, df2])

###--------------------------------------------###
# Statistical Operations
# min, max, mean, count, unique, correlation

# count 
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def count(df):
    return df.count().compute()

# sum
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def sum(df, cname):
    return df[cname].sum().compute()

# mean
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def mean(df):
    return df.mean().compute()

# min
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def min(df):
    return df.min().compute()
# max
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def max(df):
    return df.max().compute()

# unique
@measure_energy(handler=csv_handler)
def unique(df):
    return df.unique().compute()


print("Starting Adult Dask Process...")
for i in range(10):
    # Input output functions 
    df = load_csv(path='../Datasets/adult.csv')
    sleep()
    df = load_json(path='../Datasets/adult.json')
    sleep()
    df = load_hdf(path='../Datasets/adult_dask.h5', key='a')
    sleep()
    
    save_csv(df, f'df_adult_dask{i}.csv')
    sleep()
    save_json(df, f'df_adult_dask{i}.json')
    sleep()
    save_hdf(df, f'df_adult_dask{i}.hdf', key='a')
    sleep()

    # --------------------------------------------------

    # Handling missing data
    df = pd.read_csv('../Datasets/adult.csv')
    sleep()
    isna(df, cname='workclass')
    sleep()
    dropna(df)
    sleep()
    fillna(df, val='0')
    sleep()
    replace(df, cname='workclass', src='?', dest='X')

    # --------------------------------------------------
    # Table operations
    df = pd.read_csv('../Datasets/adult.csv')
    sleep()
    df_samp = pd.read_csv('../Datasets/adult.csv')
    sleep()
    drop(df, cnameArray=['age', 'education'])
    sleep()
    groupby(df, cname='workclass')
    sleep()
    
    concat_dataframes(df, df_samp)
    sleep()
    
    sort(df, 'age')
    sleep()
    merge(df, df_samp)
    sleep()

    # ------------------------------------------
    # Statistical operations
    df = pd.read_csv('../Datasets/adult.csv')
    sleep()
    count(df)
    sleep()
    sum(df, 'capital-gain')
    sleep()
    mean(df['age'])
    sleep()
    min(df['capital-gain'])
    sleep()
    max(df['capital-gain'])
    sleep()
    unique(df['age'])
    sleep()

    print(f"Finished iteration {i+1}")

print("Process complete")
csv_handler.save_data()




Python 3.9.13
Pandas Version: 2.2.2
Dask Version: 2024.8.0
PyJoules for energy measurement

Error Message:
When I run the script using python .\measure_adult_dask.py, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Princy Chauhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1806, in _create_storer
    cls = _TABLE_MAP[tt]
KeyError: None

...

TypeError: cannot properly create the storer for: [_TABLE_MAP] [group->/a (Group) '',value-><class 'NoneType'>,format->None


It seems to be an issue with how the HDF5 file is being accessed or how the storer is being created. I’ve double-checked the file path and key, and they seem correct.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the HDF5 file exists at the specified location.
I attempted to load the HDF5 file directly using Pandas.read_hdf (without Dask), and it works fine.
Question:
How can I resolve this issue? Is there something specific to Dask’s HDF5 handling that I'm missing? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Could you try to provide a simpler and reproducible example failing with Dask but working with Pandas?
